# Nada acontece no success, mesmo tendo retorno do Json

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

O retorno está dando 200 do Json, porém nada é excutado no success.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#form_result').html('');
  $.ajax({
   url:"/dashboard/admin/titulos/"+id+"/edit",
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(html){
    alert("não roda nada dentro do SUCCESS")
   }
  })
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há duas possibilidades.

A primeira possibilidade é sua requisição retornar um HTML, pois analizando essa linha `$('#form_result').html('');` dá a entender que você apagou o código HTML de `form_result` e está pronto para colocar o resultado de sua requisição no lugar. 
Nesse cenário o valor para o retorno de `dataType:"json"` estaria causando o problema, pois se um JSON mal formado for retornado mesmo a operação tendo resultado com um `Status HTTP 200` o callback `success()` não será invocado e nesse caso é retornado um HTML.

Então para corrigir é só adequar o `dataType` a requisição:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#form_result').html('');
    $.ajax({
       url:"/dashboard/admin/titulos/"+id+"/edit",
       dataType:"html",  //<-- Aqui onde era JSON virou HTML
       success:function(html){
          $('#form_result').html(html);
       }
    })
});
```

`success()` só é chamado se não houver erro com servidor e não houver erro com a estrutura dos dados retornados, implicando que um html mal formado vindo do servidor também seria problema caso o formato especificado seja alterado para html.

---

A segunda possibilidade, menos plausível, é de que realmente o retorno possa ser um JSON só que ele está mal formado impedindo a execução de `success()`. Então quando não tem certeza da consistência do dado retornado, ou há consciência da possibilidade de falha no processo de confecção do dado ou ainda se há a necessidade de se trabalhar os dados na recepção use `.done()` que é invocado quando o retorno do servidor é Ok independente dos dados retornados.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#form_result').html('');
  $.ajax({
     url:"/dashboard/admin/titulos/"+id+"/edit",
     dataType:"json" 
  })
  .done(function(html){
     alert("Agora funciona");         
  });
});
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Sua resposta foi uma aula.

Comment: Realmente o json estava mal formado, fiz a correção do retorno no backend e funcionou